# How to set permission to write file from another library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-permissions, writefile

I want to write a text file to internal storage but from another library. When I set permission manually to my app(storage permission) it works but the below codes can not handle this.

This is my code in another library,mkdir always return false:

```
  File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mydir");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdir()) {
            Log.i("App", "failed to create directory");
        }
    }
```

Should I set some permission in the Manifest file?

Comment: `When I set permission manually to my app(storage permission) it works but the below codes can not handle this.` ??? You first say that it works and then tht it does not work. ??

Comment: if (!mediaStorageDir.canWrite() ) Toast ( sorry can not write to this dir)

Comment: Always use mkdirs().